# Searching for a specific node of an unsorted tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, backtracking

The general idea is to traverse a tree using recursive backtracking (of BinaryNode, data is Character), to find a specific char. The method would output the path from root to the node whose data is the specified char. Moving left would mean the path would have 0, and moving right would mean the path would have 1. So, for example, the path to the uppermost root node is an empty string, the path to the left child is 0 (and 1 for the right child).

So far, I have it a recursive void method whose base case is if the match is found, and the method ends. Otherwise, if there is a left child i call the method again, then check and/or call for right child as well. the last section would be that the current root is a leaf node, and there I would modify the stored path to eliminate the most recently added 0 or 1, and then return to the previous recursive call. Here is what I have so far

```
//method head
if(c==root.getData()) return;

if(root.hasLeftChild()) //call method with left child as root, and a 0 added to path

//same for right child, only add a 1 instead of a 0

//if leaf node aka neither left or right child, path will now be a substring from 0 to path.length()-1
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Since no implementation of BinaryNode is provided, i simply use some basic methods it should provide.

```
public String getPath(char c , BinaryNode<Character> node){
     if(node.getData() == c)//matching node found
          return "";

     if(node.right() != null){//check if right child is parent of match
          String tmp = getPath(c , node);
          if(tmp != null)//match found -> complete path from this node
               return "1" + tmp;
     }
     if(node.left() != null){//check if left child is parent of match
          String tmp = getPath(c , node);
          if(tmp != null)
               return "0" + tmp;
     }

     //c is no content of the tree with node as root -> return null
     return null;
}
```

This code does all in one. While it goes deeper into the tree it searches for the matching node and when the algorithm goes back to the root of the tree, the path is generated backwards (result is in the correct order).

Comment: Thank you so much! People like you are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

```
recurAndFind(String str, Node x, char c){
if(x== null);
if(x.getChar() == c)
   return str;
else if(x.hasLeft())
    recurAndFind("0"+str,x.left,c);
else if(x.hasright())
     recurAndFind("1"+str,x.right,c);
}
```

This will do what you are trying to do, but you will have to check once you receive the String what are the contents and make the decision accordingly. You need to send it an empty string.

Comment: Thank you so much! People like you are awesome!!